# two's complement - what if there's one more bit needed to represent a binary in 2's complement form

Tags: binary

I’m doing computer science A-level course in a high school and currently working on two’s complement arithmetic. For some reason I don’t quite get it. I know how to convert a signed integer into its two’s complement equivalent, but here’re my confusions:

1. I’ve done some research and people say the op-code which is the carry-bit tells the CPU if a 2’s complement code represents a positive integer or a negative, but sometimes the carry-bit is ignored according to some people; for instance, adding 1111 (-1) to 1000 (-8) you get 10111 (-9), but if it’s a 4-bit computer, the most significant bit which is the 5th bit cannot be stored, so how does the computer deal with that ?
2. A somewhat trivial question is if it’s given that 00110011 represent a signed integer in two’s complement form, how do I know if the actual code is 0110011, which is a positive number (in 2’s complement form), or 110011, which is a negative number (in 2’s complement form) ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, what doesn't fit is lost. So, 1111<sub>2</sub> + 1000<sub>2</sub> = 0111<sub>2</sub>. However, some CPUs have special flags which get set to 0 or 1 depending on whether or not there's unsigned overflow (the carry flag) and signed overflow (the overflow flag). Some CPUs may be able to automatically raise an overflow exception when an arithmetic instruction can't produce result without overflow.

Typically, the CPU does not care if 1111<sub>2</sub> is -1<sub>10</sub> or 15<sub>10</sub>. Binary addition and subtraction of two N-bit integers gives you the same N-bit sum or difference irrespective of whether you're operating on unsigned integers or 2's complement signed integers. The same is true when multiplying two N-bit signed 2's complement or unsigned integers: the N least significant bits of the product is the same in both cases.

IOW, it's your job to keep track of what types you're manipulating, to take care of overflows (if they're possible) and to select proper instructions for those types (e.g. you typically have signed and unsigned division, signed and unsigned comparison, etc).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Basically I understand the CPU doesn't care if a binary code is + or - when manipulating, however, I have a specific example here that maybe better explain what's tricky for me:

Comment: when adding 0101 (+5) to 1111(in this case can either be -1 or 15), we get 10100 as a result. If we ignore the leading 1, it becomes 0100 which is the sum of 5 and -1; but when we keep the leading 1, it becomes 10100 which is the sum of 5 and 15...So I'm confused how the computer choose to ignore the overflown bit in order to derive the correct answer?

Comment: @Francis.Tricka The CPU doesn't choose here. It simply does N-bit + N-bit = N-bit addition. Where N is typically 8, 16, 32 or 64, the size of the general-purpose register in the CPU. Addition is done from least significant digits towards most significant digits, right? So you can stop the process after computing N bits of the sum.

Comment: Oh I see how it works, but why the  the overflow-bit doesn't affect the correct calculation when lost, as the lost bit represents a number ?

Comment: @Francis.Tricka How can the overflow flag affect the result? And why should it? (there's extra complexity in setting the flag and doing something else in addition to modifying the flag) If you care about the overflow, you check the flag. Often you don't care or are certain that there's no overflow and so you don't check the flag.

Comment: @Francis.Tricka In some cases it may be handy (or otherwise worthwhile) to perform the ALU operation in more bits than in the operands. E.g. your CPU provides only 32-bit + 32-bit = 32-bit addition, but you want the correct sum, which won't fit into 32 bits. So, you can extend the 32-bit operands to 64 bits each (using sign extension or zero extension as appropriate for the assumed type of your 32-bit operands) and chain two 32-bit additions with a carry out from the first into the second.